# Does Geometry Nodes use Memory or CPU when instancing?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

When using Geometry Nodes  what part of the computer
does it use when instancing, i.e.,  memory, cpu?   When I try
to instance large areas the computer is unable to process.
My computer is 2014 vintage and likely the "problem."  It would
still be great to know the answer.  Thanks in advance for any
insight.

Comment: I think the answer is neither and both, as I understand the trick is to offload what can be parallelized directly to the GPU instead when instancing. But of course it still requires some memory and some regular computational capacity.

Comment: This is like asking if you use bread or peanut butter when making peanut butter sandwich

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the responses.

I love peanut butter sandwiches – but your “analogy” hasn’t answered
my question.   I still don’t know why my computer chokes when I increase the
density of the Distribute Points on Faces node?

Is it because of a lack of memory,  outdated processing power, or both, or
am I not implementing the nodes correctly, or using a Mac and no access to 
a GPU,  or do I just need to invest in a new computer.

Thank you, again for responding.

Comment: Like the sandwich analogy both are sued for different purposes during different phases of the process. The CPU is used for processing the data while calculating any changes, while the memory is used to store the result after it has been calculated. If you computer chokes after making changes then it may be a CPU bottleneck, if it stutters afterwards it may be a lack of memory issue, if you get choppy viewport performance while rotating the view it may be the CPU or the graphics card. Most often it is an arbitrary combination of all the previous.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for taking the time to share more information –
It’s appreciated.  

With Apple joining Blender’s Development Fund, maybe improved
performance is in the future.

Thanks, again.